# Using renderView() in a custom ModuleAdminController (PS1.6)

Tags: php, module, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am trying to add the view action to my back office module page but i cannot display anything with the renderview() function. I can already display my list with renderList() and it's working well. I also tried renderForm() and it works well too but it seemz i can't get renderView() to display something.

```
public function renderView(){

    if(!($config = $this->loadObject())){
        return;
    }

    $data = Config::getDataForm(Tools::getValue('id_config'));
    // var_dump($data);

    $this->tpl_view_vars = array(
        'id_config' => $data['id_config'],
        'prix' => $data['prix'],
        'hauteur' => $data['hauteur_passage']
        );

    return parent::renderView();

}
```

This is a pretty basic code. My getDataForm($id_config) is getting fields from database in an array so that i can display it. I can see the var_dump displaying for a short time before displaying the blank page with prestashop header and footer. I tried to see if i was doing something wrond by checking other AdminController such as AdminCartsController or AdminCustomersController but it seems that their renderView() function is more or less written the same way.

Thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manage to resolve this problem simply by adding a view tpl in /modules/mymodule/views/templates/admin/mymodule/helpers/view/.

I wrongly assumed that it didn't need to create a template file for the view action as it didn't need one for the list and form action. After searching through modules and admin files i managed to find that there were indeed a custom view.tpl for the view action.

The renderview() method lets you set up the variables you want to use in your view.tpl.

For more information on how it works, you can check AdminCustomersController to see how it is on the controller side and /adminxxxx/themes/default/template/controllers/customers/helpers/view/view.tpl to see how the template is written.

Feel free to edit or comment if you need more information

Comment: If your controller is named, let's say ```AdminGreatCustomersController```, your folder name will be named ```/modules/mymodule/views/templates/admin/great_customers/helpe‌​rs/view/```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a configuration page on your module, you'll have to add this function to your module :

```
public function getContent()
{
    // return some html content
}
```

If you want to use a controller, then you'll have to create a Controller that extends `ModuleAdminController` and add it in the tabs of the back-office.

Comment: This renderview() method is already part of a ModuleAdminController. What i wanted to achieve is the "view" part of the back office admin module which appears when you click on an item in the list. You can see this "view" page in the Customer admin page and it lets you see more information on your customers.

Comment: Then in your original post, you should have mentioned that you are using a ModuleAdminController. Look at other controllers then, it's exactly the same code

Comment: It's written in the title.

Comment: My bad. In my defense, this part was not clear : "a view to my back office module" :D

Comment: True. I should have said i was referring to the view action of an admin page ;)